# Activiti version 8.1.x: Not getting inbound variables in connector

Tags: java, spring-boot, activiti

Spring boot version 3.6
activiti version : 8.1.0

Context: I have a POC application created where i need to simulate user task in activiti via API, for which i have created a connector on `update Approval` as highligted in below xml file.
Now, when i start worklfow, the system is sucessfully able to register the workflow and when i fetch all pending task for that given user who can approve. but when i try to push the approval using below code with setting the variables for the task, few things i'm unable to figure out how to do it the right way
1.

```
List<VariableInstance> variables = taskRuntime.variables(TaskPayloadBuilder.variables().withTaskId(taskId).build());
```

This above code is not able to get variables which were sent to workflow while it was created

workaround to which was done using below code

```
Map<String, Object> vars = taskService.getVariables(taskId);
```

2. 

Below piece of code i done see any persisted entery in RU_Variables table

```
taskRuntime.complete(TaskPayloadBuilder.complete()
                    .withTaskId(taskId)
                    .withVariable(VAR_REGISTRATION_REQUEST, contentToProcess)
                    .withVariable("comment", taskRequest.getComment())
                    .withVariable("approved", taskRequest.isApproved()).build());
```

3. The task complete triggered on 2. triggeres below code where i the size of `getInBoundVariables` is 0

```
@Bean
    public Connector updateRegistrationStatusConnector() {
        return integrationContext -> {
            Map<String, Object> inBound = integrationContext.getInBoundVariables();

            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("inBoundVariables --> {}", inBound);
            }
            Map<String, Object> inBoundVariables = (Map<String, Object>) inBound.get("inbound");
            UserRegistrationRequest registrationRequest = (UserRegistrationRequest) inBoundVariables.get(VAR_REGISTRATION_REQUEST);
            String comment = (String) inBoundVariables.get("comment");
            Boolean approved = (Boolean) inBoundVariables.get("approved");
           saveRegistrationStatus(registrationRequest.getUserId(), comment, approved);
            return integrationContext;
        };
    }
```

```
public Task completeTask(String taskId, TaskCompletionRequest taskRequest) {
        Task task = null;
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            task = taskRuntime.task(taskId);

            //Map<String,Object> variables = runtimeService.getVariables(task.getProcessDefinitionId());
            List<VariableInstance> variables = taskRuntime.variables(TaskPayloadBuilder.variables().withTaskId(taskId).build());
            Map<String, Object> vars = taskService.getVariables(taskId);
            //UserRegistrationRequest contentToProcessNode = Objects.requireNonNull(variables.stream().filter(var -> VAR_REGISTRATION_REQUEST.equals(var.getName())).findFirst().orElse(null)).getValue();
            UserRegistrationRequest contentToProcess = (UserRegistrationRequest) vars.get(VAR_REGISTRATION_REQUEST);

            /*CreateTaskVariablePayloadBuilder builder = new CreateTaskVariablePayloadBuilder();
            taskRuntime.createVariable(builder.withTaskId(taskId)
                    .withVariable("comment", taskRequest.getComment())
                    .withVariable("approved", taskRequest.isApproved()).build());*/

            HashMap<String,Object> map  = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(VAR_REGISTRATION_REQUEST, contentToProcess);
            map.put("comment", taskRequest.getComment());
            map.put("approved", taskRequest.isApproved());
           CreateTaskVariablePayloadBuilder builder = new CreateTaskVariablePayloadBuilder();
           builder.withVariable("inbound",map);
            task = taskRuntime.complete(TaskPayloadBuilder.complete()
                    .withTaskId(taskId)
                    .withVariable(VAR_REGISTRATION_REQUEST, contentToProcess)
                    .withVariable("comment", taskRequest.getComment())
                    .withVariable("approved", taskRequest.isApproved()).build());
            builder.withTaskId(task.getId());
            taskRuntime.createVariable(builder.build());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error",e);
            throw new UserRegistrationTaskException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return task;
    }
```

below is the Activiti.bpmn20.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:tns="http://www.activiti.org/test" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" id="m1603026671390" name="" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <process id="userRegistrationProcess" isClosed="false" isExecutable="true" processType="None">
        <startEvent id="start" name="StartEvent"/>
        <userTask activiti:exclusive="true" id="sendApproval" name="Send Approval" activiti:assignee="${registrationRequest.approverId}" />
        <sequenceFlow id="_4" sourceRef="start" targetRef="sendApproval"/>
        <serviceTask activiti:exclusive="true" id="updateApprovalStatus" name="Update Approval Status" implementation="***updateRegistrationStatusConnector***" />
        <sequenceFlow id="_6" sourceRef="sendApproval" targetRef="updateApprovalStatus"/>
        <exclusiveGateway gatewayDirection="Unspecified" id="approvalCheck" name="Approved?">
        </exclusiveGateway>
        <sequenceFlow id="_8" sourceRef="updateApprovalStatus" targetRef="approvalCheck"/>
        <endEvent id="end" name="EndEvent"/>
        <sequenceFlow id="_10" name="no" sourceRef="approvalCheck" targetRef="end">
            <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression">
                <![CDATA[${approved == false}]]>
            </conditionExpression>
        </sequenceFlow>
        <userTask activiti:exclusive="true" id="updateProfile" name="Update Profile" activiti:assignee="${registrationRequest.userId}"/>
        <sequenceFlow id="_2" name="yes" sourceRef="approvalCheck" targetRef="updateProfile">
            <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression">
                <![CDATA[${approved == true}]]>
            </conditionExpression>
        </sequenceFlow>
        <sequenceFlow id="_3" sourceRef="updateProfile" targetRef="end"/>
    </process>
    <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram documentation="background=#3C3F41;count=1;horizontalcount=1;orientation=0;width=842.4;height=1195.2;imageableWidth=832.4;imageableHeight=1185.2;imageableX=5.0;imageableY=5.0" id="Diagram-_1" name="New Diagram">
        <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="userRegistrationProcess">
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="start" id="Shape-start">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="32.0" width="32.0" x="75.0" y="90.0"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="32.0" width="32.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sendApproval" id="Shape-sendApproval">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="85.0" x="205.0" y="80.0"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="85.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="updateApprovalStatus" id="Shape-updateApprovalStatus">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="85.0" x="365.0" y="80.0"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="85.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="approvalCheck" id="Shape-approvalCheck" isMarkerVisible="false">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="32.0" width="32.0" x="540.0" y="90.0"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="32.0" width="32.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="end" id="Shape-end">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="32.0" width="32.0" x="660.0" y="90.0"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="32.0" width="32.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="updateProfile" id="Shape-updateProfile">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="85.0" x="515.0" y="215.0"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="85.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_2" id="BPMNEdge__2" sourceElement="approvalCheck" targetElement="_11">
                <omgdi:waypoint x="556.0" y="122.0"/>
                <omgdi:waypoint x="556.0" y="215.0"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="0.0" width="0.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
            <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_3" id="BPMNEdge__3" sourceElement="_11" targetElement="_9">
                <omgdi:waypoint x="600.0" y="242.5"/>
                <omgdi:waypoint x="675.0" y="175.0"/>
                <omgdi:waypoint x="675.0" y="121.96871942267131"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="0.0" width="0.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
            <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_4" id="BPMNEdge__4" sourceElement="start" targetElement="sendApproval">
                <omgdi:waypoint x="107.0" y="106.0"/>
                <omgdi:waypoint x="205.0" y="107.5"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="0.0" width="0.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
            <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_6" id="BPMNEdge__6" sourceElement="sendApproval" targetElement="updateApprovalStatus">
                <omgdi:waypoint x="290.0" y="107.5"/>
                <omgdi:waypoint x="365.0" y="107.5"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="0.0" width="0.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
            <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_8" id="BPMNEdge__8" sourceElement="updateApprovalStatus" targetElement="approvalCheck">
                <omgdi:waypoint x="450.0" y="107.5"/>
                <omgdi:waypoint x="540.0" y="106.0"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="0.0" width="0.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
            <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_10" id="BPMNEdge__10" sourceElement="approvalCheck" targetElement="_9">
                <omgdi:waypoint x="572.0" y="106.0"/>
                <omgdi:waypoint x="660.0" y="106.0"/>
                <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                    <omgdc:Bounds height="0.0" width="0.0" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
                </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
            </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
        </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
    </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

Note: the same code with activiti 7.1.123 & spring boot 2.1 is working perfrectly

1. I did some research around the documentation on 8.x activiti, i didn't find any. if someone can help me with that will also be helpful
2. when i dig deeper into the code the one thing i was able to find is activiti task is looking only for local variables for the code

```
List<VariableInstance> variables = taskRuntime.variables(TaskPayloadBuilder.variables().withTaskId(taskId).build());
```

for which i could get the global variables using `taskService`